# Transfer a cartodb legacy map to carto builder and keep the same url publish link

Tags: carto, update, hyperlink

I have several cartodb legacy map layers that are already embedded in a separate website, is there a way to update the map to the new carto builder without changing the embed link?

Essentially, take the an old map in the old interface and update it to the new interface and functions without changing the link address.

I have tried adding the same dataset to a new map but that creates a new link and I have tried exporting the map and uploading it in a new map, which gives me the new functionality, but also gives a new link to the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating a map from CARTO Editor to BUILDER, the URL and vizjson are going to change (see url examples below). Regarding the 1st, `viz` and `public_map` will be replaced by `builder` and `embed` respectively. So you will need to change these after applying the change. In relation to vizjson changes, there is a possibility that some details from the Editor map could change or missed as explained [here](https://carto.com/learn/guides/intro/migrating-from-carto-editor-to-carto-builder#temporary-limitations). So for this reason, there is a warning when opening an Editor map with BUILDER. I highly recommend making a copy just in case.

- Editor public map url: https://team.carto.com/u/ramirocartodb/viz/1c4669e2-28cc-11e7-9e5b-0ee66e2c9693/public_map
- BUILDER embed url: https://team.carto.com/u/ramirocartodb/builder/1c4669e2-28cc-11e7-9e5b-0ee66e2c9693/embed